# JsView Select does not display selected option immediately after clicking on it

Tags: jsviews

I ran into a case where selecting of an option that is data bound to my javascript data object resulted into a different option being shown as selected.

Example data object:

```
var data = {
    "person": { "no" : 2 },
    "options": [
        {"no":0,"t":"null"},
        {"no":1,"t":"a"},
        {"no":2,"t":"b"},
        {"no":3,"t":"c"}
    ]
};
```

Corresponding Select with the data binding setup:

```
<script id="SelectTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <select id="MySelect" data-link="person.no">
        <option value=""></option>
        {^{for options}}
        <option data-link="{:t} value{:no} selected{:no === ~root.person.no}"></option>
        {{/for}}
    </select>
</script>
```

I have created a JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/parthsha/vu57yd0z/5/) to play with my setup. Can anyone please explain to me why this is happening? Or what I am doing wrong?

**Note:**
I would like to share my current *workaround* just in case someone else happens to run into this problem. I am listening to property change event on my select data bound object (i.e. person). Here is what it looks like:

```
$(data.person).on('propertyChange', function (event, eventArgs) {
    $("#MySelect").val(eventArgs.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using integer values: `no:1` rather than `no:"1"`.

Those values get converted to string when set as values of the corresponding option element. So when the user selects a new item, the value person.no is set to a string `"2"`, say, which fails the comparison `:no === ~root.person.no`.

So here are four alternative fixes:

**1:** If you don't want to support having dynamic changes to the `t` or `no` values, then you don't need to data-link those values on the option, but can set them statically in the initial rendering:

```
<select data-link="person.no">
    {^{for options}}
        <option value="{{:no}}">{{:t}}</option>
    {{/for}}
</select>
```

-but `person.no` will still get switched to a string value after selection, unless you use a converter: `<select data-link="{:person.no:toNum}">` (see #4 below...)

**2:** If you want to keep the data-bound values, you can change from using from integers to using string values.

**3:** Keep the integers and simply make the comparison non-strict: `<option data-link="{:t} value{:no} selected{:no == ~root.person.no}"></option>` -  but again, `person.no` will get switched to a string value after selection...

**4:** Keep the integers and convert back to integer, so the number type is preserved:

```
$.views.converters("toNum", function(val) {
    return +val;
})
```

and

```
<select data-link="{:person.no:toNum}">
    {^{for options}}
        <option data-link="{:t} value{:no} selected{:no === ~root.person.no}"></option>
    {{/for}}
</select>
```

(So now `person.no` will have a number value after selection...)

*BTW - **side note***: for your workaround you could have used an alternative - specific for changes to `person.no`, so it will not break if other properties of `person` get changed:

```
$.observe(data.person, "no", function (event, eventArgs) {
    $("#MySelect").val(eventArgs.value);
});
```

rather than

```
$(data.person).on('propertyChange', function (event, eventArgs) {
    $("#MySelect").val(eventArgs.value);
});
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed the type check. Thank you so much for the different fix options.